# selector with table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html table, and i add a class on one row.
The class is applied this way, and i later want to swap the rows.

```
$('.bTable').on('click', 'tbody tr', function(event) {

       if($(this).attr('class')!='highlightgreen'){
            $(this).addClass('highlightgreen').siblings().removeClass('highlightgreen');

       }else{
            $(this).removeClass('highlightgreen');
       }
});
```

I cant seem to be able to select that class row with `eq()`.

Error example: i try to `alert()` the a and the row appears fine, i `alert()` the b, and null comes up.

```
var a = $('.bTable tbody tr').eq(0);
var b = $('.bTable tbody tr .highlightgreen').eq(0);
```

How can i select properly that `.highlightgreen` row?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `.eq`, your selector is wrong. `.bTable tbody tr .highlightgreen` looks for elements with class `highlightgreen` *inside* each row. The space is the *descendant selector*.

Comment: in addition to that, use `.hasClass()` or `.is()` to determine state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When selecting a TR with a class, you do `$('tr.className')`, notice there are no spaces.
When selecting an element ***inside*** a TR that has a class, you do `$('tr .className')`.

So just remove the space

```
var b = $('.bTable tbody tr.highlightgreen').eq(0);
```

And `eq(0)` will get the first element in the collection

```
$('.bTable').on('click', 'tbody tr', function(event) {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlightgreen')
           .siblings().removeClass('highlightgreen');
});
```